# Two level listview with embedded sub items (image)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I would like to create a layout that would basically look like the image below.

Items are dynamic so a flavor of ListView ou ExpandableListView seems like a way to go but I'm curious to see if anyone would know of an existing component or a way of implementing it.

I don't care about collapsing the groups.

Thanks!

[image: My example]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about collapsing groups (i.e. all children are displayed, always) you can get away using just a listview (or recycleview).

This means you can store your data simply as a list (instead of a list of lists), since all your items are defined simply as their position in the list (instead of a pair of indexes: e.g. group/child).

To do this, you would override the ListView getViewType and getViewTypeCount methods.  I'd direct you to an existing post on how to implement those methods if you don't already know: [Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Comment: I've considered using that technique but it doesn't allow me to "embed" the sub items (to have them appear inside the parent's box). So far, my best guess is to use a RecyclerView for groups with a HorizontalView inside of it and to add the items programmatically...

Comment: Yes, to achieve the embed effect a recycleView inflating ViewGroups (corresponding to "group 1,2.3...", which you can extend to support dynamically adding children should work.